# Get shape name in specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have some oval shapes in active sheet and I have tried to return shape name from specific cell using the following udf

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print GetShapeName(Range("J10"))
End Sub

Function GetShapeName(cell As Range) As String
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In cell.Parent.Shapes
        If Not Application.Intersect(shp.TopLeftCell.MergeArea, cell) Is Nothing Then
            GetShapeName = shp.Name
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next shp
    GetShapeName = ""
End Function
```

But I got empty result. I tried to remove `MergeArea` but the same problem.
The shapes is drawn by the following code if that can help

```
Sub VBA_Circle_Text()
    Dim cel As Range, m As Double, n As Double
    Set cel = Application.Selection
    With cel
        m = .Height * 0.1
        n = .Width * 0.1
        Application.ActiveSheet.Ovals.Add Top:=.Top - m, Left:=.Left - n, Height:=.Height + 2.25 * m, Width:=.Width + 1.75 * n
        With Application.ActiveSheet.Ovals(ActiveSheet.Ovals.Count)
            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            With .ShapeRange.Line
                .Weight = 2
                .ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
            End With
        End With
    End With
    cel.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: If you try returning the shape **immediately after its creation**, is there any issue? If not, maybe the cell dimensions have been changed (row/column autofit, decreased etc.). It should be returned **only if its top left coordonate is inside the respective cell area**...

Comment: Could it be, that you expect the selected cell where you add the oval as the topleftcell?
It is not. Select it and look where the topleftcell is. I guess it is up and left of the selected cell.

Comment: How can I detect the shape in such a case regardless the topleftcelll property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function GetShapeName(cell As Range) As String
    Dim shp As Shape, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = cell.Parent
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        If Not Application.Intersect(ws.Range(shp.TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & shp.BottomRightCell.Address), cell) Is Nothing Then
            GetShapeName = shp.Name
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next shp
    GetShapeName = ""
End Function
```

and a variant that returns an array of the names of all the shapes in the range

```
Function GetShapesNames(cell As Range) As Variant
    Dim shp As Shape, ws As Worksheet, result As String
    Set ws = cell.Parent
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        If Not Application.Intersect(ws.Range(shp.TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & shp.BottomRightCell.Address), cell) Is Nothing Then
            result = (result & IIf(result <> "", ",", "") & shp.Name)
        End If
    Next shp
    GetShapesNames = Split(result, ",")
End Function
```

Comment: The first udf returns a result but the shape from another cell. I think I need to adjust the topleftcell but I couldn't after many tries.

Comment: I have changed this line in the first UDF and I could adjust it to return the shape name as expected `If Not Application.Intersect(ws.Range(shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(1, 1).Address), cell) Is Nothing Then`